# Problems with update linux kernel`

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have issue with update my kernel on Centos. 
I'll try yo update the system and got the next error :

```
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    kernel-2.6.32-573.1.1.el6.x86_64 from CentOS6-Updates-x86_64
```

Can somebody help me? what I must do to update it? It doesn't help me:

```
yum clean all
```

If this important I used CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

Thanks

My repolist :

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * elrepo: repos.lax-noc.com
repo id                                                                  repo name                                                                                         status
CentOS-6.6-x86_64-0                                                      CentOS-6.6-x86_64-0                                                                                6,479
CentOS-6.x-x86_64-Base                                                   CentOS-6.x-x86_64-Base                                                                             6,518
CentOS6-Updates-x86_64                                                   CentOS6-Updates-x86_64                                                                               161
EPEL-6Server-x86_64                                                      EPEL-6Server-x86_64                                                                               11,641

repolist: 25,674
```

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the dbcache (not the local cache) by using the following commands:

```
yum clean dbcache
yum update
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i still receive this error.

Comment: Use `yum repolist` to see what repos are active and put the output here.

Comment: See [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/711510/centos-6-6-final-yum-kernel-upgrade-troubles) . It should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks I seen this post, but it did not help me :(